# Passar o valor do combobox pra um outro campo

Tags: php, javascript, html, api

No código abaixo eu passo o valor de `Nome` da peça para *$value(detalhe estou usando os dados da API pois é usado tbm em c#)* e ele é mostrado na `combobox` para o usuário selecionar qual peça quer:

```
     <label for="sel1">Peça</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="peca" name="peca">
        <?php
                $json_file =  
                file_get_contents("http://tcc2016.esy.es/API/nomePecas");
                $json_str = json_decode($json_file);
                $lista = array();

                foreach($json_str as $key=>$value)
                {
                    $ID_Peca = ($json_str[$key]->ID_Peca);  
                    $nome_Peca = ($json_str[$key]->nome_Peca);
                    $preco_Peca = ($json_str[$key]->preco_Peca);            
                    $m = array("ID_Peca"=> "$ID_Peca" ,"Nome Peca" => 
                    "$nome_Peca", "Preco Peca" => "$preco_Peca");

                    foreach (array($m['Nome Peca']) as $value) {

                    echo"<option>".$value."</option>";                     
                       echo "<br>";
                    }

                }


        ?>
      </select>
     </form>
```

Mas ai vem a segunda parte, preciso usar o valor que o usuário selecionou na `combobox` para pegar o valor do preço da peça e mostrar para usuário no campo de baixo pois a peça já é cadastrada com o preço, assim mostrar o preço dela pra ele ao selecionar um item no `combobox`, acredito que eu precise usar o `ID`, mas não consigo chamar ele e depois chamar a peça:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputdefault"><font color="#8e1c1c">Preço</font></label>
      <label class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="number" name="preco">
          <?php


            ?>
        </label>
  </div>
```

Eu vi coisas como usar java script, tipo:

```
<script>
    function f()
     {
       var element = document.getElementById("peca").value;
       var seletedValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
       window.location = "cadastro.php?parametro=selectedValue;"
     }
   </script>
```

O problema é que eu não tenho ideia de como usar isso ou chamar transformar ele para o `php`.

Estou a muitas horas tentando fazer isso funcionar e só falta isso para eu terminar, mas não estou conseguindo!

Comment: Leia a pergunta que escreveu e veja que sem saber o contexto... como podemos ajudar? Mostre o que está a buscar e como, para que possamos responder.

Comment: eu melhorei a pergunta então se puder rever seria de muita ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Olá! tenta fazer assim no seu select: < select onchange="f()">
pois quando selecionar a opção vai disparar sua função f()